# For Civ V, where can I find a list of city names used by each civilization?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing a game on a Standard map with 7 other Civs, however it seems as though one was captured before I could even explore it, and now I'd like to liberate it.   My knowledge of dead cultures is somewhat poor, is there a chart that lists what city names, or at least the capital names, belong to what civilizations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a list of city names per civilization in your Civilization V folder inside the file `/Assets/Gameplay/XML/Civilizations/Civ5Civilizations.xml`.

It contains only the identifiers of the city names (e.g. `TXT_KEY_CITY_NAME_NEW_YORK`), not the full, localized name.

The localized name of each city is in the file `/Assets/Gameplay/XML/NewText/EN_US/CIV5GameText_Cities.xml`. The `EN_US`-part is your locale, you have to change that if you're not playing the english version.

**List of city names per civilization:**

```
AMERICA WASHINGTON
AMERICA NEW_YORK
AMERICA BOSTON
AMERICA PHILADELPHIA
AMERICA ATLANTA
AMERICA CHICAGO
AMERICA SEATTLE
AMERICA SAN_FRANCISCO
AMERICA LOS_ANGELES
AMERICA HOUSTON
AMERICA PORTLAND
AMERICA ST_LOUIS
AMERICA MIAMI
AMERICA BUFFALO
AMERICA DETROIT
AMERICA NEW_ORLEANS
AMERICA BALTIMORE
AMERICA DENVER
AMERICA CINCINNATI
AMERICA DALLAS
AMERICA MEMPHIS
AMERICA CLEVELAN
AMERICA KANSAS_CITY
AMERICA SAN_DIEGO
AMERICA RICHMOND
AMERICA LAS_VEGAS
AMERICA PHOENIX
AMERICA ALBUQUERQUE
AMERICA MINNEAPOLIS
AMERICA PITTSBURGH
AMERICA OAKLAND
AMERICA TAMPA_BAY
AMERICA ORLANDO
AMERICA TACOMA
AMERICA SANTA_FE
AMERICA OLYMPIA
AMERICA HUNT_VALLEY
AMERICA SPRINGFIELD
AMERICA PALO_ALTO
AMERICA CENTRALIA
AMERICA SPOKANE
AMERICA JACKSONVILLE
AMERICA SAVANNAH
AMERICA CHARLESTON
AMERICA SAN_ANTONIO
AMERICA OMAHA
AMERICA BIRMINGHAM
AMERICA HONOLULU
AMERICA ANCHORAGE
AMERICA SACRAMENTO
AMERICA SALT_LAKE_CITY
AMERICA RENO
AMERICA BOISE
AMERICA MILWAUKEE
AMERICA SANTA_CRUZ
AMERICA MONTEREY
AMERICA SANTA_MONICA
AMERICA LITTLE_ROCK
AMERICA COLUMBUS
AMERICA LE_BAM
ARABIA MECCA
ARABIA MEDINA
ARABIA DAMASCUS
ARABIA BAGHDAD
ARABIA NAJRAN
ARABIA KUFAH
ARABIA BASRA
ARABIA KHURASAN
ARABIA ANJAR
ARABIA FUSTAT
ARABIA ADEN
ARABIA YAMAMA
ARABIA MUSCAT
ARABIA MANSURA
ARABIA BUKHARA
ARABIA FEZ
ARABIA SHIRAZ
ARABIA MERW
ARABIA BALKH
ARABIA MOSUL
ARABIA AYDAB
ARABIA BAYT_RAS
ARABIA SUHAR
ARABIA TAIF
ARABIA HAMA
ARABIA TABUK
ARABIA SANAA
ARABIA SHIHR
ARABIA TRIPOLI
ARABIA TUNIS
ARABIA KAIROUAN
ARABIA ALGIERS
ARABIA ORAN
ARABIA TANGIER
ARABIA CASABLANCA
ARABIA MARRAKECH
AZTEC TENOCHTITLAN
AZTEC TEOTIHUACAN
AZTEC TLATELOLCO
AZTEC TEXCOCO
AZTEC TLAXCALA
AZTEC CALIXTLAHUACA
AZTEC XOCHICALCO
AZTEC TLACOPAN
AZTEC ATZCAPOTZALCO
AZTEC TZINTZUNTZEN
AZTEC MALINALCO
AZTEC TULA
AZTEC TAMUIN
AZTEC TEAYO
AZTEC CEMPOALA
AZTEC CHALCO
AZTEC TLALMANALCO
AZTEC IXTAPALUCA
AZTEC HUEXOTLA
AZTEC TEPEXPAN
AZTEC TEPETLAOXTOC
AZTEC CHICONAUTLA
AZTEC ZITLALTEPEC
AZTEC COYOTEPEC
AZTEC TEQUIXQUIAC
AZTEC JILOTZINGO
AZTEC TLAPANALOYA
AZTEC TULTITAN
AZTEC ECATEPEC
AZTEC COATEPEC
AZTEC CHALCHIUITES
AZTEC CHIAUHITA
AZTEC CHAPULTEPEC
AZTEC ITZAPALAPA
AZTEC AYOTZINCO
AZTEC IZTAPAM
CHINA BEIJING
CHINA SHANGHAI
CHINA GUANGZHOU
CHINA NANJING
CHINA XIAN
CHINA CHENGDU
CHINA HANGZHOU
CHINA TIANJIN
CHINA MACAU
CHINA SHANDONG
CHINA KAIFENG
CHINA NINGBO
CHINA BAODING
CHINA YANGZHOU
CHINA HAERBIN
CHINA CHONGQING
CHINA LOYANG
CHINA KUNMING
CHINA TAIPEI
CHINA SHENYANG
CHINA TAIYUAN
CHINA TAINAN
CHINA DALIAN
CHINA LIJIANG
CHINA WUXI
CHINA SUZHOU
CHINA MAOMING
CHINA SHAOGUAN
CHINA YANGJIANG
CHINA HEYUAN
CHINA LIAONING
CHINA HUBEI
CHINA GANSU
CHINA HUANGSHI
CHINA YICHANG
CHINA YINGTAN
CHINA XINYU
CHINA XINZHENG
CHINA HANDAN
CHINA DUNHUANG
CHINA GAOYU
CHINA NANTONG
CHINA WEIFANG
CHINA XIKANG
EGYPT THEBES
EGYPT MEMPHIS
EGYPT HELIOPOLIS
EGYPT ELEPHANTINE
EGYPT ALEXANDRIA
EGYPT PIRAMESSES
EGYPT GIZA
EGYPT BYBLOS
EGYPT AKHETATEN
EGYPT HIERACONPOLIS
EGYPT ABYDOS
EGYPT ASYUT
EGYPT AVARIS
EGYPT LISHT
EGYPT BUTO
EGYPT EDFU
EGYPT PITHOM
EGYPT BUSIRIS
EGYPT KAHUN
EGYPT ATHRIBIS
EGYPT MENDES
EGYPT ELASHMUNEIN
EGYPT TANIS
EGYPT BUBASTIS
EGYPT THIS
EGYPT ORYX
EGYPT SEBENNYTUS
EGYPT AKHMIN
EGYPT KARNAK
EGYPT LUXOR
EGYPT ELKAB
EGYPT ARMANT
EGYPT BALAT
EGYPT ELLAHUN
EGYPT GHURAB
EGYPT HAWARA
EGYPT DASHUR
EGYPT RAQOTE
EGYPT DAMANHUR
EGYPT MERIMDE
EGYPT ABUSIR
EGYPT HERAKLEOPOLIS
EGYPT AKORIS
EGYPT BENIHASAN
EGYPT TASA
EGYPT BADARI
EGYPT HERMOPOLIS
EGYPT AMRAH
EGYPT NEGADE
EGYPT KOPTOS
EGYPT HERMONTHIS
EGYPT OMBOS
EGYPT ANIBA
EGYPT SOLEB
EGYPT SEMNA
EGYPT AMARA
ENGLAND LONDON
ENGLAND YORK
ENGLAND NOTTHINGHAM
ENGLAND HASTINGS
ENGLAND CANTERBURY
ENGLAND COVENTRY
ENGLAND WARWICK
ENGLAND NEWCASTLE
ENGLAND OXFORD
ENGLAND LIVERPOOL
ENGLAND DOVER
ENGLAND BRIGHTON
ENGLAND NORWICH
ENGLAND LEEDS
ENGLAND READING
ENGLAND BIRMINGHAM
ENGLAND RICHMOND
ENGLAND EXETER
ENGLAND CAMBRIDGE
ENGLAND GLOUCESTER
ENGLAND MANCHESTER
ENGLAND BRISTOL
ENGLAND LEICESTER
ENGLAND CARLISLE
ENGLAND IPSWICH
ENGLAND PORTSMOUTH
ENGLAND BERWICK
ENGLAND BATH
ENGLAND MUMBLES
ENGLAND SOUTHAMPTON
ENGLAND SHEFFIELD
ENGLAND SALISBURY
ENGLAND COLCHESTER
ENGLAND PLYMOUTH
ENGLAND LANCASTER
ENGLAND BLACKPOOL
ENGLAND WINCHESTER
ENGLAND HULL
FRANCE PARIS
FRANCE ORLEANS
FRANCE LYONS
FRANCE RHEIMS
FRANCE TOURS
FRANCE MARSEILLES
FRANCE CHARTRES
FRANCE AVIGNON
FRANCE ROUEN
FRANCE GRENOBLE
FRANCE DJION
FRANCE AMIENS
FRANCE CHERBOURG
FRANCE POITIERS
FRANCE TOULOUSE
FRANCE BAYONNE
FRANCE STRASBOURG
FRANCE BREST
FRANCE BORDEAUX
FRANCE RENNES
FRANCE NICE
FRANCE SAINT_ETIENNE
FRANCE NANTES
FRANCE REIMS
FRANCE LE_MANS
FRANCE MONTPELLIER
FRANCE LIMOGES
FRANCE NANCY
FRANCE LILLE
FRANCE CAEN
FRANCE TOULON
FRANCE NIMES
FRANCE LE_HAVRE
FRANCE LOURDES
FRANCE CARCASSONNE
FRANCE CANNES
FRANCE AIX_EN_PROVINCE
FRANCE LA_ROCHELLE
FRANCE BOURGES
FRANCE CALAIS
GERMANY BERLIN
GERMANY HAMBURG
GERMANY MUNICH
GERMANY COLOGNE
GERMANY FRANKFURT
GERMANY ESSEN
GERMANY DORTMUND
GERMANY STUTTGART
GERMANY DUSSELDORF
GERMANY BREMEN
GERMANY HANNOVER
GERMANY DUISBURG
GERMANY LEIPZIG
GERMANY DRESDEN
GERMANY BONN
GERMANY BOCHUM
GERMANY BIELEFELD
GERMANY KARLSRUHE
GERMANY GELSENKIRCHEN
GERMANY WIESBADEN
GERMANY MUNSTER
GERMANY ROSTOCK
GERMANY CHEMNITZ
GERMANY BRAUNSCHWEIG
GERMANY HALLE
GERMANY MONCHENGLADBACH
GERMANY KIEL
GERMANY WUPPERTAL
GERMANY FREIBURG
GERMANY HAGEN
GERMANY ERFURT
GERMANY KASSEL
GERMANY OBERHAUSEN
GERMANY HAMM
GERMANY SAARBRUCKEN
GERMANY KREFELD
GERMANY POTSDAM
GERMANY SOLINGEN
GERMANY OSNABRUCK
GERMANY LUDWIGSHAFEN
GERMANY LEVERKUSEN
GERMANY OLDENBURG
GERMANY NEUSS
GERMANY MULHEIM
GERMANY DARMSTADT
GERMANY HERNE
GERMANY WURZBURG
GERMANY RECKLINGHAUSEN
GERMANY GOTTINGEN
GERMANY WOLFSBURG
GERMANY KOBLENZ
GERMANY HILDESHEIM
GERMANY ERLANGEN
GREECE ATHENS
GREECE SPARTA
GREECE CORINTH
GREECE ARGOS
GREECE KNOSSOS
GREECE MYCENAE
GREECE PHARSALOS
GREECE EPHESUS
GREECE HALICARNASSUS
GREECE RHODES
GREECE ERETRIA
GREECE PERGAMON
GREECE MILETOS
GREECE MEGARA
GREECE PHOCAEA
GREECE SICYON
GREECE TIRYNS
GREECE SAMOS
GREECE MYTILENE
GREECE CHIOS
GREECE PAROS
GREECE TEGEA
GREECE ELIS
GREECE SYRACUSE
GREECE HERAKLEIA
GREECE GORTYN
GREECE CHALKIS
GREECE PYLOS
GREECE PELLA
GREECE NAXOS
GREECE SICYON
GREECE SMYRNA
GREECE LARISSA
GREECE APOLLONIA
GREECE MESSENE
GREECE ORCHOMENOS
GREECE AMBRACIA
GREECE KOS
GREECE KNIDOS
GREECE AMPHIPOLIS
GREECE PATRAS
GREECE LAMIA
GREECE NAFPLION
GREECE APOLYTON
INDIA DELHI
INDIA MUMBAI
INDIA VIJAYANAGARA
INDIA PATALIPUTRA
INDIA VARANASI
INDIA AGRA
INDIA CALCUTTA
INDIA LAHORE
INDIA BANGALORE
INDIA HYDERABAD
INDIA MADURAI
INDIA AHMEDABAD
INDIA KOLHAPUR
INDIA PRAYAGA
INDIA AYODHYA
INDIA INDRAPRASTHA
INDIA MATHURA
INDIA UJJAIN
INDIA GULBARGA
INDIA JAUNPUR
INDIA RAJAGRIHA
INDIA SRAVASTI
INDIA TIRUCHIRAPALLI
INDIA THANJAVUR
INDIA BODHGAYA
INDIA KUSHINAGAR
INDIA AMARAVATI
INDIA GAUR
INDIA GWALIOR
INDIA JAIPUR
INDIA KARACHI
IROQUOIS ONONDAGA
IROQUOIS OSININKA
IROQUOIS GRAND_RIVER
IROQUOIS AKWESASNE
IROQUOIS BUFFALO_CREEK
IROQUOIS BRANTFORD
IROQUOIS MONTREAL
IROQUOIS GENESSE_RIVER
IROQUOIS CANANDAIGUA_LAKE
IROQUOIS LAKE_SIMCOE
IROQUOIS GRAND_RIVER
IROQUOIS SALAMANCA
IROQUOIS GOWANDA
IROQUOIS BUFFALO
IROQUOIS CUBA
IROQUOIS AKRON
IROQUOIS KANESATAKE
IROQUOIS GANIENKEH
IROQUOIS CAYUGA_CASTLE
IROQUOIS CHONDOTE
IROQUOIS CANAJOHARIE
IROQUOIS NEDROW
IROQUOIS SYRACUSE
IROQUOIS ONEIDA_LAKE
IROQUOIS KANONWALOHALE
IROQUOIS GREEN_BAY
IROQUOIS SOUTHWOLD
IROQUOIS MOHAWK_VALLEY
IROQUOIS SCHOHARIE
IROQUOIS BAY_OF_QUINTE
IROQUOIS KANAWALE
IROQUOIS KANATSIOKAREKE
IROQUOIS TYENDINAGA
IROQUOIS HAHTA
JAPAN KYOTO
JAPAN OSAKA
JAPAN TOKYO
JAPAN SATSUMA
JAPAN KAGOSHIMA
JAPAN NARA
JAPAN NAGOYA
JAPAN IZUMO
JAPAN NAGASAKI
JAPAN YOKOHAMA
JAPAN SHIMONOSEKI
JAPAN MATSUYAMA
JAPAN SAPPORO
JAPAN HAKODATE
JAPAN ISE
JAPAN TOYAMA
JAPAN FUKUSHIMA
JAPAN SUO
JAPAN BIZEN
JAPAN ECHIZEN
JAPAN IZUMI
JAPAN OMI
JAPAN ECHIGO
JAPAN KOZUKE
JAPAN SADO
JAPAN KOBE
JAPAN NAGANO
JAPAN HIROSHIMA
JAPAN TAKAYAMA
JAPAN AKITA
JAPAN FUKUOKA
JAPAN AOMORI
JAPAN KAMAKURO
JAPAN KOCHI
JAPAN NAHA
OTTOMAN ISTANBUL
OTTOMAN EDIRNE
OTTOMAN ANKARA
OTTOMAN BURSA
OTTOMAN KONYA
OTTOMAN SAMSUN
OTTOMAN GAZIANTEP
OTTOMAN DIYARBAKIR
OTTOMAN IZMIR
OTTOMAN KAYSERI
OTTOMAN MALATYA
OTTOMAN MARSIN
OTTOMAN ANTALYA
OTTOMAN ZONGULDAK
OTTOMAN DENIZLI
OTTOMAN OIDU
OTTOMAN MUGLA
OTTOMAN ESKISEHIR
OTTOMAN INEBOLU
OTTOMAN SINOP
OTTOMAN ADANA
OTTOMAN TARSUS
OTTOMAN ARTUIN
OTTOMAN BODRUM
OTTOMAN EREGLI
OTTOMAN SILIFKE
OTTOMAN SIVAS
OTTOMAN AMASYA
OTTOMAN MARMARIS
OTTOMAN TRABZON
OTTOMAN ERZURUM
OTTOMAN URFA
OTTOMAN IZMIT
OTTOMAN AFYON
OTTOMAN BITLIS
OTTOMAN MARMARIS
PERSIA PERSEPOLIS
PERSIA PASARGADAE
PERSIA SUSA
PERSIA ECBATANA
PERSIA TARSUS
PERSIA GORDIUM
PERSIA BACTRA
PERSIA SARDIS
PERSIA ERGILI
PERSIA DARIUSHKABIR
PERSIA GHULAMAN
PERSIA ZOHAK
PERSIA ISTAKHR
PERSIA JINJAN
PERSIA BORAZJAN
PERSIA HERAT
PERSIA DAKYANUS
PERSIA BAMPUR
PERSIA TURENGTEPE
PERSIA REY
PERSIA SHIRAZ
PERSIA TUSHPA
PERSIA HASANLU
PERSIA GABAE
PERSIA MERV
PERSIA BEHISTUN
PERSIA KANDAHAR
PERSIA ALTINTEPE
PERSIA BUNYAN
PERSIA CHARSADDA
PERSIA URATYUBE
PERSIA DURAEUROPOS
PERSIA ALEPPO
PERSIA QATNA
PERSIA KABUL
PERSIA CAPISA
PERSIA KYRESKHATA
PERSIA MARAKANDA
PERSIA PESHAWAR
PERSIA VAN
PERSIA PTEIRA
PERSIA ARSHADA
PERSIA ARTAKOANA
PERSIA ASPABOTA
PERSIA AUTIYARA
PERSIA BAGASTANA
PERSIA BAXTRI
PERSIA DARMASA
PERSIA DAPHNAI
PERSIA DRAPSAKA
PERSIA EION
PERSIA GANDUTAVA
PERSIA GAUGAMELA
PERSIA HARMOZEIA
PERSIA EKATOMPYLOS
PERSIA IZATA
PERSIA KAMPADA
PERSIA KAPISA
PERSIA KARMANA
PERSIA KOUNAXA
PERSIA KUGANAKA
PERSIA NAUTAKA
PERSIA PAISHIYAUVADA
PERSIA PATIGRBANA
PERSIA PHRADA
ROME ROME
ROME ANTIUM
ROME CUMAE
ROME NEAPOLIS
ROME RAVENNA
ROME ARRETIUM
ROME MEDIOLANUM
ROME ARPINUM
ROME CIRCEI
ROME SETIA
ROME SATRICUM
ROME ARDEA
ROME OSTIA
ROME VELITRAE
ROME VIROCONIUM
ROME TARENTUM
ROME BRUNDISIUM
ROME CAESARAUGUSTA
ROME CAESAREA
ROME PALMYRA
ROME SIGNIA
ROME AQUILEIA
ROME CLUSIUM
ROME SUTRIUM
ROME CREMONA
ROME PLACENTIA
ROME HISPALIS
ROME ARTAXATA
ROME AURELIANORUM
ROME NICOPOLIS
ROME LONDINIUM
ROME EBURACUM
ROME GORDION
ROME AGRIPPINA
ROME LUGDUNUM
ROME VERONA
ROME CORFINIUM
ROME TREVERI
ROME SIRMIUM
ROME AUGUSTADORUM
ROME BAGACUM
ROME LAURIACUM
ROME TEURNIA
ROME CURIA
ROME FREGELLAE
ROME ALBAFUCENS
ROME SORA
ROME INTERRAMA
ROME SUESSA
ROME SATICULA
ROME LUCERIA
ROME ARMINIUM
ROME SENAGALLICA
ROME CASTRUMNOVUM
ROME HADRIA
RUSSIA MOSCOW
RUSSIA STPETERSBURG
RUSSIA NOVGOROD
RUSSIA ROSTOV
RUSSIA YAROSLAVI
RUSSIA YEKATERINBURG
RUSSIA YAKUTSK
RUSSIA VLADIVOSTOK
RUSSIA SMOLENSK
RUSSIA ORENBURG
RUSSIA KRASNOYARSK
RUSSIA KHABAROVSK
RUSSIA BRYANSK
RUSSIA TVER
RUSSIA NOVOSIBIRSK
RUSSIA MAGADAN
RUSSIA MURMANSK
RUSSIA IRKUSTK
RUSSIA CHITA
RUSSIA SAMARA
RUSSIA ARKHANGELSK
RUSSIA CHELYABINSK
RUSSIA TOBOLSK
RUSSIA VOLOGDA
RUSSIA OMSK
RUSSIA ASTRAKHAN
RUSSIA KURSK
RUSSIA SARATOV
RUSSIA TULA
RUSSIA VLADIMIR
RUSSIA PERM
RUSSIA VORONEZH
RUSSIA PSKOV
RUSSIA STARAYARUSSA
RUSSIA KOSTROMA
RUSSIA NIZHNIYNOVGOROD
RUSSIA SUZDAL
RUSSIA MAGNITOGORSK
SIAM SUKHOTHAI
SIAM SI_SATCHANALAI
SIAM MUANG_SALUANG
SIAM LAMPANG
SIAM PHITSANULOK
SIAM KAMPHAENG_PHET
SIAM NAKHON_CHUM
SIAM VIENTIANE
SIAM NAKHON_SI_THAMMARAT
SIAM MARTABAN
SIAM NAKHON_SAWAN
SIAM CHAINAT
SIAM LUANG_PRABANG
SIAM UTTARADIT
SIAM CHIANG_THONG
SIAM PHRAE
SIAM NAN
SIAM TAK
SIAM SUPHANBURI
SIAM HONGSAWADEE
SIAM THAWAII
SIAM AYUTTHAYA
SIAM TAPHAN_HIN
SIAM UTHAI_THANI
SIAM LAP_BURI
SIAM RATCHASIMA
SIAM BAN_PHAI
SIAM LOCI
SIAM KHAN_KAEN
SIAM SURIN
SONGHAI GAO
SONGHAI TOMBOUCTU
SONGHAI JENNE
SONGHAI TAGHAZA
SONGHAI TONDIBI
SONGHAI KUMBI_SALEH
SONGHAI KUKIA
SONGHAI WALATA
SONGHAI TEGDAOUST
SONGHAI ARGUNGU
SONGHAI GWANDU
SONGHAI KEBBI
SONGHAI BOUSSA
SONGHAI MOPTI
SONGHAI BAMAKO
SONGHAI WA
SONGHAI KAYES
SONGHAI AWDAGHOST
SONGHAI OUADANE
SONGHAI DAKAR
SONGHAI TADMEKKET
SONGHAI TEKEDDA
SONGHAI KANO
SONGHAI AGADEZ
SONGHAI NIAMEY
SONGHAI TORODI
SONGHAI OUATAGOUNA
SONGHAI DORI
SONGHAI BAMBA
SONGHAI SEGOU
MINOR CHEROKEE
MINOR ANASAZI
MINOR TEOIHUACAN
MINOR OLMEC
MINOR ZAPOTEC
MINOR CHINOOK
MINOR APACHE
MINOR CHEHALIS
MINOR ILLINOIS
MINOR NAVAJO
MINOR CARIB
MINOR SAXON
MINOR VANDAL
MINOR GOTH
MINOR ANGLE
MINOR MAGYAR
MINOR KHAZAK
MINOR BULGAR
MINOR ALEMANNI
MINOR BURGUNDIAN
MINOR GEPID
MINOR HUN
MINOR JUTE
MINOR PHEONICIAN
MINOR ESTRUSCAN
MINOR THRACIAN
MINOR PHRYGIAN
MINOR GAUL
MINOR MINOAN
MINOR MYCENIAN
MINOR CIMMERIAN
MINOR LIGURIAN
MINOR NUMIDIAN
MINOR SARMATIAN
MINOR SCYTHIAN
MINOR VISIGOTH
MINOR ASSYRIAN
MINOR HITTITE
MINOR HARAPPAN
MINOR MAURYAN
MINOR PARTHIAN
MINOR HARAPPAN
MINOR NUBIAN
MINOR BACTRIAN
MINOR CIRCASSIAN
MINOR CUMAN
MINOR HURRIAN
MINOR KASSITE
MINOR BANTU
MINOR KHOISAN
MINOR LIBYAN
MINOR SHANGIAN
MINOR YAYOI
MINOR ZHOU
MINOR AINU
MINOR POLYNESIAN
MINOR ARYAN
MINOR AVAR
MINOR GHUZZ
MINOR HSUNGNU
MINOR KUSHANS
MINOR YUECHI
MINOR SAKAE
MINOR UZBEK
MINOR TARTAR
BARBARIAN CHEROKEE
BARBARIAN ANASAZI
BARBARIAN TEOIHUACAN
BARBARIAN OLMEC
BARBARIAN ZAPOTEC
BARBARIAN CHINOOK
BARBARIAN APACHE
BARBARIAN CHEHALIS
BARBARIAN ILLINOIS
BARBARIAN NAVAJO
BARBARIAN CARIB
BARBARIAN SAXON
BARBARIAN VANDAL
BARBARIAN GOTH
BARBARIAN ANGLE
BARBARIAN MAGYAR
BARBARIAN KHAZAK
BARBARIAN BULGAR
BARBARIAN ALEMANNI
BARBARIAN BURGUNDIAN
BARBARIAN GEPID
BARBARIAN HUN
BARBARIAN JUTE
BARBARIAN PHEONICIAN
BARBARIAN ESTRUSCAN
BARBARIAN THRACIAN
BARBARIAN PHRYGIAN
BARBARIAN GAUL
BARBARIAN MINOAN
BARBARIAN MYCENIAN
BARBARIAN CIMMERIAN
BARBARIAN LIGURIAN
BARBARIAN NUMIDIAN
BARBARIAN SARMATIAN
BARBARIAN SCYTHIAN
BARBARIAN VISIGOTH
BARBARIAN ASSYRIAN
BARBARIAN HITTITE
BARBARIAN HARAPPAN
BARBARIAN MAURYAN
BARBARIAN PARTHIAN
BARBARIAN HARAPPAN
BARBARIAN NUBIAN
BARBARIAN BACTRIAN
BARBARIAN CIRCASSIAN
BARBARIAN CUMAN
BARBARIAN HURRIAN
BARBARIAN KASSITE
BARBARIAN BANTU
BARBARIAN KHOISAN
BARBARIAN LIBYAN
BARBARIAN SHANGIAN
BARBARIAN YAYOI
BARBARIAN ZHOU
BARBARIAN AINU
BARBARIAN POLYNESIAN
BARBARIAN ARYAN
BARBARIAN AVAR
BARBARIAN GHUZZ
BARBARIAN HSUNGNU
BARBARIAN KUSHANS
BARBARIAN YUECHI
BARBARIAN SAKAE
BARBARIAN UZBEK
BARBARIAN TARTAR
```

Comment: By the way one can also get the city names of scenarios, which are not in Civilization's wiki, if you `grep` your game folder. For example, city names of Korea's scenario are located at `Assets/DLC/DLC_05/Scenarios/KoreaScenario/NewMajorCivCities.xml` and `Assets/DLC/DLC_05/Gameplay/XML/Text/en_US/CIV5GameTextInfos_Cities_KoreanScenario.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can search the [civilization wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Civilization_Games_Wiki).

For example, here is [the list of Brazil's cities](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Brazilian_%28Civ5%29#City_list):

- Rio de Janeiro (formerly a City-State) (capital from 1763 to 1960 and capital in Rio de Janeiro State)
- São Paulo (largest city in Brazil and capital in São Paulo State)
- Salvador (capital from 1549 to 1763 and capital in Bahia)
- Brasília (current Brazilian capital)
- Fortaleza (capital in Ceará)
- Belo Horizonte (capital and largest city in Minas Gerais)
- Manaus (capital in Amazonas)
- Curitiba (capital and largest city in Paraná)
- Recife (capital and largest city in Pernambuco)
- Porto Alegre (capital and largest city in Rio Grande do Sul)
- Belém (capital and largest city in Pará)
- Goiânia (capital and largest city in Goiás)
- Guarulhos
- Campinas
- São Luis (capital in Maranhão)
- Maceió (capital in Alagoas)
- Duque de Caxias
- Natal (capital and largest city of Rio Grande do Norte)
- Campo Grande (capital in Mato Grosso do Sul)
- Teresina (capital in Piauí)
- Florianópolis (capital of Santa Cantarina)
- Nova Iguaçu
- Sao Bernardo do Campo
- João Pessoa (capital and largest city of Paraiba)
- Osasco
- Jaboatão dos Guararapes
- São José dos Campos
- Contagem
- Uberlândia
- Aracaju (capital and largest city of Sergipe)
- Cuiabá (capital in Mato Grosso)
- Feira de Santana
- Juiz de Fora
- Joinville (largest city of Santa Cantarina)
- Macapá (capital in Amapá)

The goodness is that you can see the brief introductions for the cities.