# What will happen if you build cities more than the built-in names

Tags: civilization-5

Just an imaginary case, what if you have built enough cities (say, 40), which probably exceeds the number of the built-in city list of that civilization?

Comment: Used to happen all the time in civ 4. If you didn't have about 30 cities you were doing it wrong!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will continue with names like `New <BuiltInCity1>`, `New <BuiltInCity2>`..

BTW you can get [complete list of city names](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/for-civ-v-where-can-i-find-a-list-of-city-names-used-by-each-civilization).

Comment: Localised to the culture (that is, UK gets "New London", Dutch "Nieuw Amsterdam", Germans "Neu-Berlin", Polish "Warszawa Nowa", Japanese "新東京" and so on), the user language, or just generic "New ..."?

Comment: I guess it's always generic 'New', at least on my non-English locale.

Comment: So you can build New New York? Awesome!

Comment: Its correct that on the first loop the name is New X... usually. There are a few exceptions in the form of easter eggs. Constantinople becomes Not Constantinople, in reference to the They Might be Giants song. New Tokyo is actually Neo Tokyo (most likely an Akira reference). These names have existed in the previous games in the series as well.

Comment: So the third loop would be `New New <BuiltInCity_n>`?